# Flutter: network_info_plus broken on m1 max

Tags: ruby, flutter, cocoapods, shared-libraries

Already posted a bug at the publicly held package on github, but here's what's going on.

- Create a brand new flutter application on an M1 Max Mac.
- Add the network_info_plus dependency in your pubspec.yaml.
- Open up the iOS simulator for iPhone 13 Pro.
- Run the application in Android studio.
- Observe the error:

```sh
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle (LoadError)
```

Pubspec.yaml relevant packages:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.13
  sembast: ^3.2.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.9
  network_info_plus: ^2.1.3
```

Package reference link:
https://pub.dev/packages/network_info_plus

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an environment issue.  I was messing around with ruby on my mac and I think that might have killed my builds to iOS.  What ended up fixing it was running `gem install cocoapods` and my builds magically started working.

I also deleted my pubspec.lock as well and redownloaded my assets.  I ran `flutter clean`. Between the above and wiping my pubspec.lock and redownloading my packages, one of those seemed to fix it.